# how to make 3 boxes goes under each other on smaller devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

hi guys I'm trying to create 3 boxes ,one big and two smalls one next to it and add imaged inside of the boxes .The problem is in small devices i want the 3 boxes goes under each other instead of sticking to each other like,in other words they are not responsive.I'm working on it for 3 days now and i can not get it .

```css
.fashion_look img {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.main-container .block-container .fashion_look .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 35px;
}

.main-container .block-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.main-container .widget-static-block {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.main-container .block-container .banner_top,
.main-container .block-container .new_shoes,
.main-container .block-container .fashion_look {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="widget widget-static-block">
  <div class="block-container">
    
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="fashion_look">
        <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
        <a href="https://www.acureorganics.com/skin.html"><img src="https://www.acureorganics.com/media/wysiwyg/acure/570_1a.jpg"></a><br>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="new_shoes">
            <div class="overlay">&nbsp;</div>
            <img  src="https://www.acureorganics.com/media/wysiwyg/acure/banner-YEAH.jpg">
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="banner_top">
            <a href="https://www.acureorganics.com/body.html"><img src="https://www.acureorganics.com/media/wysiwyg/acure/banner-BODY.jpg"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="banner_top">
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-xs-6 to col-xs-12 and a good advice is to read well the bootstrap doc to understand the breakpoint and the classes

Comment: You are using Bootstrap. But at the same time you defy it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for taking your time to answer my question so its wrong?

Comment: @MarioWerner Thank you for taking your time to answer my question how can i fix this ??

Comment: as I said col-xs-6 to col-xs-12

Comment: so do you want me to remove it?

Comment: Can you help me with it please I'm working on for 3 days now and i'm really lost

Comment: well, simply change col-xs-6 to col-xs-12, I hope it's clear :)

Comment: you are the besttttttttttttt man it works